# Fill PDF forms from the shell

Tags: shell, command-line, pdf, poppler

Is there a tool to fill PDF forms non-interactively from the shell?

For my use case, just setting the text for each field (in whatever order the fields are defined) and saving the PDF file would be enough, but to keep the question more general, any form interaction via CLI is appreciated (tick boxes, select radio buttons, fill text, click buttons, etc.).

I know that poppler has [some functions](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/api/glib/PopplerFormField.html) to access PDF forms, but I couldn't find a CLI utility that makes use of these, yet.

Comment: For an industrial-strength solution, you might look at FDFMerge by Appligent.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, `pdftk` has this option. From `man pdftk`

> `fill_form <FDF data filename | XFDF data filename | - | PROMPT>`
>
> Fills the single input PDF's form fields with the data from
> an FDF file, XFDF file or stdin. Enter the data filename af‐
> ter fill_form, or use - to pass the data via stdin, like so:
>
> `pdftk form.pdf fill_form data.fdf output form.filled.pdf`

**How to do?**

**1. Extract field names**

```
pdftk forms.pdf dump_data_fields
```

will drop a list with e.g. entries like:

```
---
FieldType: Text
FieldName: Name_Last
FieldNameAlt: LAST
FieldFlags: 0
FieldJustification: Left
---
```

**2. Create `fdf`-file**

`fdf`-files are form-fillers. We use the general notation as

```
<< /T(FIELD_NAME)/V(FIELD_VALUE) >>
```

And need to add a header and footer. [Source](https://www.sitepoint.com/filling-pdf-forms-pdftk-php/)

```
%FDF-1.2
1 0 obj<</FDF<< /Fields[
<< /T (Name_Last) /V (Smith) >>
<< /T (Name_First) /V (John) >>
] >> >>
endobj
trailer
<</Root 1 0 R>>
%%EOF
```

To be saved as `input.fdf`

**3. Create the document**

```
pdftk forms.pdf fill_form input.fdf output filled.pdf
```

**4. Maybe you want to check again?**

```
pdftk filled.pdf dump_data_fields

---
FieldType: Text
FieldName: Name_Last
FieldNameAlt: LAST
FieldFlags: 0
FieldValue: Smith
FieldJustification: Left
---
```

So the last name has made it into the document.

**5. Additional handling**

For radio buttons, the value is one of the `FieldStateOption`-entries, for checkboxes use `V(Yes)` and `/V(Off)`.

---

If you want to make it more of a line-by-line query type of thing, you might want to wrap a script around it that reads the field types and names and prompts for input, then automatically creates the `fdf`-file. But that is a small project of its own.

Alternatively, you might like the [`xfdf`-format (which see)](https://docs.appligent.com/fdfmerge/fdfmerge-form-data-format/#creatinganxfdffile) better. It is based on `xml`-style entries.

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed answer. XFDF seems to be more easily generated (given that there are xml libraries for every language/framework), so that's what I will probably try first.

Comment: That seems to only work for filling forms reported in the FDF/XFDF file. How can a apply an FDF/XFDF file of annotations (I exported the FDF/XFDF file from Acrobat) to a PDF?

Comment: @Geremia - that is a separate question

Comment: for part '2. Create fdf-file', you can also use pdftk: `pdftk infile.pdf generate_fdf output foo.fdf`